# fullcalendar does not renderEvent in IE (All versions)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, fullcalendar

I'm using [fullcalendar](http://fullcalendar.io) to render some events.

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/alexintime/rho79s7w/7/) - press a day and enter a number in the textbox

The fullcalendar "setup" is as follows:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: false,
        defaultView: 'basicWeek',
        height: 300,
        firstDay: 1,
        columnFormat: 'ddd D/MM',
        dayClick: function (date, jsEvent, view) {
            if (date > new Date()) {
                $('#lateralert').show();
                setInterval(function () { $('#lateralert').hide(); }, 4000);
            } else {
                $('#AddEventModal').modal('show');
                var modal = $('#AddEventModal');
                document.getElementById('hiddendate').value = date.toString();
                modal.find('.modal-title').text((moment(date).format('ddd D/MM')));
            }
        },
        events: [
            {
                title: '3',
                start: '2015-04-13',
                backgroundColor: '#e74c3c',
                borderColor: '#e74c3c'
            },
            {
                title: '4,5',
                start: '2015-04-13',
                backgroundColor: '#3498db',
                borderColor: '#3498db'

            },
            {
                title: '2',
                start: '2015-04-13',
                backgroundColor: '#95a5a6',
                borderColor: '#95a5a6'
            }
        ]
        // put your options and callbacks here
    });

});
```

I'm submitting these events through a form where I catch the submit and add the event.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#event_frm').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var form = document.getElementById('event_frm');

        var date = form.elements["hiddendate"].value;
        var hours = form.elements["hours"].value;

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent',
        {
            title: hours,
            start: date,
            allDay: true,
            description: 'my desc'
        });

        window.hasMadeChanges = true;

        $('#discardchanges').prop('disabled', false);
    });
});
```

The above works correctly in Firefox, I've tried debugging it in IE, but there are no errors, and the code executes (according to the debugger), but no events are added to the calendar when using IE 9 -> Edge.

Am I missing something obvious here or?

In Firefox:

[image: firefox]

In IE:

[image]

Comment: You are using Visual Studio??

Comment: Aren't you getting any error when you debug. I mean exception kinda break in js file particularly `fullcalendar.js`??

Comment: No errors, no. the console is clean (so to speak)

Comment: Try keeping a break point in `var date` and once you cross add a watch to them and check what's the value??

Comment: Everything has correct values - its the "renderEvent" part that seemingly doesn't do anything in IE :S

Comment: Some of the links to help you - **[Link1](https://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=891)** and **[Link 2](https://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=1059)**

Comment: What version of fullcalendar? And don't use `renderEvent`, use [`addEventSource`](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/addEventSource/)

Comment: @slicedtoad Version 2.3.1 - I tried changing renderEvent to addEventSource - but it did no difference to the outcome.

Comment: ok, let's try wrapping date in a `moment`. Stick `console.log(moment(date).format())` just above `renderEvent`. Does it log the correct date in both FF and IE?

Comment: Tried it, and yes - it does contain the correct date.

Comment: Ill check as soon as possible

Comment: The fiddle works in IE

Comment: It still works - Ill try to create one for you tommorow if thats okay? :) thanks for all your help so far

Comment: @slicedtoad -> working example - click a day, enter a number press Add. http://jsfiddle.net/alexintime/rho79s7w/7 - works in FF but not IE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, found two problems and got it to work in IE9.

Fullcalendar uses [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) for everything date related. If you hardcode in the insert date as a moment, you'll notice that it works in IE.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent',{          
    title: hours,
    start: moment(),
    allDay: true,
    description: 'test'
});
```

So we know something is up with the start date you are supplying. Wrapping it in a moment almost works:

```
var date = form.elements["hiddendate"].value;
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent',{          
    title: hours,
    start: moment(date),
    allDay: true,
    description: 'test'
});
```

But now the event is added to the previous day.

If you look at where you got that date value:

```
document.getElementById('hiddendate').value = date.toString();
```

`toString` shouldn't be used for storing the date. I'm actually not sure what it's for ([docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/is-valid/) use it once but never talk about it).

And in your console, you'll notice a deprecation warning when you do `moment(date)`. The warning says it falls back on the `Date` constructor since it can't parse the string. This is where the IE difference is, since the `Date` object is browser dependant. `Date` on FF can read the string, but `Date` on IE can't.

Instead, use `moment.format()` which produces a string that moment can read. So:

```
document.getElementById('hiddendate').value = date.format();
//...
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent',{          
    title: "a",
    start: moment(date),
    allDay: true,
    description: 'test'
});
```

This [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rho79s7w/8/) should work now.

Also, the line:

```
if (date > new Date()) {
```

Should be

```
if (date.isAfter(moment())) {
```

I'm surprised the former even worked, but it's not supported will likely not work perfectly. Don't mix date types (unless you wrap the `Date`s in `moment()`).

Comment: Thank you very much - Yeah I tried  "start: moment(date)" and was amazed that the date was behind a day, and ToString worked (as in the docs (which i used for reference)) 
Great work @slicedtoad you are a man amongst men.

Comment: Perfect solution. I was having the same problem in IE10/11.